# How to connect to SSL/TLS servers with ESNI/ECH in Python?

Tags: python, ssl, tls1.3

From what I can see in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) for the `ssl` module, there is no control over how the Client Hello is sent to the server. Moreover, since the [Encrypted Client Hello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Encrypted_Client_Hello) extension to the TLS protocol is somewhat experimental, with Firefox only supporting it [via a hidden `about:config` option](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2021/01/07/encrypted-client-hello-the-future-of-esni-in-firefox/).

That being said, is there a way to create a connection to an SSL/TLS server with an Encrypted Client Hello from Python today? If possible, I would prefer answers that use [the `requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) so that it can be immediately applied to connecting to HTTPS endpoints.

Comment: Python just wraps openssl's bindings, so it should be supported. It's just a matter of how unpleasant it is to write the code for it :)

Comment: @AnilRedshift but the OpenSSL repo has [an open issue](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/7482) on the matter. I don't know how Firefox does it, perhaps with a patched OpenSSL or a self-written library. (At this point I'm actually considering proxying requests from my program through a Firefox instance; this is a terrible idea, but it's either that or using Tor to connect to websites that are blocked in this country.)

Comment: For ECH, both client and server need to support this and AFAIK no server has implemented ECH till now

Comment: @JustKhaithang Cloudflare apparently have: https://blog.cloudflare.com/encrypted-sni/ https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/encrypted-sni/

Comment: Are you getting a green tick in the ESNI test from firefox (after enabling ECH) ? because I am not getting it. May be since it is an experimental on Firefox and the fact that ECH is still under development. ECH is an update on the ESNI which only encrypted the SNI ( as opposed to the full client hello message ). Firefox latest release 92 probably has the draft 9 from last year. The latest draft is draft 13 from August this year. So a lot is still yet to be implemented

Comment: Okay here's an update for that. Apparently firefox is using draft 8 of ECH and the cloudflare servers are using draft 13. ECH mandates that both the client and server should be on the same version (draft ) otherwise it won't work.  ESNI on the other hand is supported in the Extended Support release version 78.14.0esr.

Comment: The link you posted checks for encrypted SNI, not ECH. So you can't test ECH with that link. This is the link to test for ECH - https://crypto.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace . Use Firefox ESR version 78.14.0esr and see whether you get the green tick